# How can you render an object similar to the DebugView property available when debugging in VS

Tags: c#

I just noticed while writing an expression, that the best way to see what your compiled expression will look like is using the DebugView property of an expression.

If i recall correctly any object can be subject to a custom DebugView - I'm wondering how to get a handle of this, since "ToString" isn't nearly as readable as this.

I suspect it is similar to WPF where you can do CollectionViewSource on any IObservableCollection, to get access to a wrapper object.

**Maybe someone knows how to generate a DebugView - having a way of rendering an expression like this without actually debugging could be fairly useful.**

[image: I want it to render like this]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> If i recall correctly any object can be subject to a custom DebugView

Yes you are correct.

What you seek is known as a *Debugger Visualizer*.   You can easily create your own by inheriting from `DialogDebuggerVisualizer`. **It is not necessary that the visualiser you make is for your own type**.  You can make a visualiser for a pre-existing .NET type like `string`. See the walkthrough below.

For expressions you would do something like:

```
[assembly:System.Diagnostics.DebuggerVisualizer(  
typeof(MyFirstVisualizer.DebuggerSide),  
typeof(VisualizerObjectSource),  
Target  = typeof(System.Linq.Expressions.Expression),  // <-- expression
Description  = "My First Visualizer")]
```

MSDN

> Visualizers are components of the Visual Studio debugger user interface. A visualizer creates a dialog box or another interface to display a variable or object in a manner that is appropriate to its data type.
>
> The architecture of a debugger visualizer has two parts:
>
> - The debugger side runs within the Visual Studio debugger. The debugger-side code creates and displays the user interface for your visualizer.
> - The debuggee side runs within the process Visual Studio is debugging (the debuggee).

Installing is very easy, just copy to

*VisualStudioInstallPath* **\Common7\Packages\Debugger\Visualizers**

...or even

**My Documents\ VisualStudioVersion \Visualizers**.

### More

- *[Create Custom Visualizers of Data](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/visualstudio/debugger/create-custom-visualizers-of-data)*
- *[Walkthrough: Writing a Visualizer in C#](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms164759.aspx)*

Comment: Waiting abit in case someone provides a way to get the DebuggerView for specific visualizers (Expression in that case) Your answer sounds like that isn't possible without using specific assemblies. I'll mark yours as answer soon, if noone knows an easy way